# a script that outputs the type of file, is it necessary to check if the file exists first

Tags: bash

im trying to write a script that asks a user for a file/directory name, determines its type (regular file, directory, or another type) then outputs a message saying its type. it is necessary to check if the file exists first in this instance. is there a more efficient way to do what im trying to?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -e "$input_name" ]; then
    echo "Error: '$input_name' does not exist."
    exit 1
fi

echo “Enter the path”
read input
if [ -f “$input” ]
  then
    echo “$input is a regular file”
elif [ -d “$input” ]
  then
    echo “$input is a directory”
else
    echo “$input is not a regular file or directory”
fi
```

Comment: Unless this is an exercise consider using the `file` utility: `file your-file` does exactly what you want and even more. See `man file` for the version you have or [the POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/file.html) if you care about portability.

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: I would do a series of tests (for instance -d, -f and at last -e) and abort once I got a hit, but this is a matter of taste. BTW, what output do you expect if the entry is a symlink to  a directory, respectively a symlink to a plain  file?

Comment: _is there a more efficient way to do_  : Since your script is probably broken (unless `input_name` happens to be an environment variable, which was set in the parent process - but you didn't mention this ), pretty much any correct script is "more efficient" than this one.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

```
res=$(file -i "$input")
case "$res" in
    *inode/directory*) echo dir    ;;
    *text/plain*)      echo file   ;;
    *)                 echo to_add ;; 
esac
```

`to_add` means *to be implemented*.

Comment: just to clarify, does 
*)                 echo to_add ;; 
cover removing the if statement so?

Comment: Yes, you can implement other cases, like `video` and so on. `*)` is a catch all for not listed cases

Comment: `-i` means something different in posix - https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/file.html

Comment: @jhnc its my first time hearing of that, thanks for the link!

Comment: But you are using bash that is not used in POSIX mode @user88888888

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, that's the typical way to do it. I'd only add that you could print the prompt with the read command instead of echo (i.e. `read -p "Enter the path: " input`) and should indent your code properly to avoid errors. Here's my cleaned up version:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter the path: " input 

if [ ! -e "$input" ]; then 
    echo "Error: '$input' does not exist." 
    exit 1 
elif [ -f "$input" ]; then 
    echo "$input is a regular file" 
elif [ -d "$input" ]; then 
    echo "$input is a directory" 
else 
    echo "$input is not a regular file or directory" 
fi
```

Since I was curious, I also asked Gemini (i.e Google's LLM) about it, and it recommended using `file` and a switch case to make it cleaner. Personally, I prefer `test` over `file` here, but I'll put it here in case you prefer it:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter the path to a file or directory: " input_name

# Check if the path exists using a single test and clearer error message
if [[ ! -e "$input_name" ]]; then
  echo "Error: '$input_name' does not exist."
  exit 1
fi

# Efficiently determine the type using file command and case statement
file_type=$(file -b --mime-type "$input_name")
case "$file_type" in
  "text/"*)
    echo "$input_name is a text file."
    ;;
  "directory/"*)
    echo "$input_name is a directory."
    ;;
  *)
    echo "$input_name is another file type: $file_type"
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, what do you mean by "I prefer test over file"?

Comment: `[conditional]` is the same as `test [conditional]`. I prefer using that over the `file` command because I think it's more readable. But as Giles pointed out, using `file` allows for the switch statement, which is easier to scale to other file types.